# Zoom effect in Galleria

Tags: jquery, zooming, galleria

I'm using Galleria to show my product images.
I want to incorporate it with another jquery plugin called zoom: http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/

It needs an element to wrap around to function, but I can't seem to find that element in Galleria.
Any idea which class should I use to activate zoom? I tried `#galleria`, `.galleria-stage`, `.galleria-container`, `.galleria-image`, `.galleria-images`

I know the zoom plugin works because I tested it on other classes in the page.

it should be simple as `$('.galleria-stage').zoom();`

My test page is here: http://store.studiove.com/collections/shop/products/manifold-clock

Answer (score 2):

You need to call zoom after each image.

```
Galleria.on('image',function(e){
    $(e.imageTarget).parent().zoom();
});
```

Comment: Although I wasn't using this plugin but your answer helped me in getting another task done! +1